# How often should the jti claim be regenerated?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am implementing a JWT based authentication system in my REST API, and am looking to use the JWT_ID claim in the token. According to [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/jwt-claims#reserved-claims), JWT ID allows a token to be used once:

> jti (JWT ID): Unique identifier; can be used to prevent the JWT from
> being replayed (allows a token to be used only once)

**I am wondering how often should the JWT ID be regenerated?**

- On every request
- On Login only
- On token refresh (if refresh token system is used)

**NOTE:** I am not using Auth0 for my authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `jti` claim usage is *optional*, so you are not required to use it at all. However, it's pretty useful when you are required to keep the track of a token, either in a white or in a blacklist.

> I am wondering how often should the JWT ID be regenerated?

I'm not sure what you mean with *regenerate*.

The value of the `jti` claim should be assigned when the token is generated. And once the token is [*signed*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515), there's no way to modify it without *invalidating the signature*. So, if you assign a new id to the token in each request, you'll have to sign the token again, so you'll end up with a new token for each request.

Here's how the `jti` claim is defined in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> [**4.1.7.  `jti` (JWT ID) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7)
>
> The `jti` (JWT ID) claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT. The identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that here is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally assigned to a different data object; if the application uses multiple issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values produced by different issuers as well.  The `jti` claim can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed.  The `jti` value is a case-sensitive string.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

---

#### Bottom line

From what I understand of your use case, it makes sense to issue a new token (with a unique id, such as [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)) when the client authenticates and when the client refreshes the token.

It is worth mentioning that the `jti` claim *on its own* does *nothing* against token replay. However it gives you means to identify the tokens and track them in a white or in a blacklist.

Comment: yes that's definitely an optional claim but I need to use it for the same purpose as you mentioned. So in that case, I should assign a JTI only when its  issued, that can be during login or when refreshing the token BUT not on every request. Did I get it correct?

Comment: @Ayan Once a signed token is issued by the server, there's no way to modify it without invalidating the signature. So, if you assign a new id to the token in each request, you'll have to sign the token again, so you'll end up with a new token in each request.

Comment: thank you for reminding as I wasn't thinking correctly. Yes, that will be ultimately refreshing my token on every request which might put a burden on the cpu.

Comment: @Ayan From what I understand of your use case, it makes sense to issue a new token (with an unique id) when the client authenticates and when the client refreshes the token.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in identifying my use case. But how does then JTI mitigate replay attacks?

Comment: @Ayan The `jti` claim on its own does nothing against token replay. However it gives you a mean to identify the tokens and track them in a white or in a blacklist.

Comment: alright. I was looking into one of JWT returned by google and found that the JTI didnt have any dashes in between but uuid produces an id containing dashes. Moreover the number of characters are also more. Ex of the id by google: `0520256e93804cd2ee3fef4dfff0be0109a5a470`. Is there any way of achieving like so?

Answer (score 1):

The `jwt_id` should only be generated upon **login** and on **token refresh**. It's best to use the **expireIn** and **maxAge** to quantify the duration of the validity of the token instead.